# Curl and posting base64 data to a php uploading script

Tags: bash, curl

I'm looking to make a script to upload images from my server to an imagehost, which has a php API.

I'm supposed to send the following html request to the API:

```
http://example.com/api?upload=myImg&key=apiKey&format=xml
```

myImg and apiKey respectively are the the image and the key, but you probably have guessed that :)

My code is:

```
curl -X POST http://example.com/api?upload="$apiImg"&key="$apiKey"&format=xml
```

When I use an remote URL as the image, it works fine.

However, to upload a local image, it has to be base64 encoded; I did that by doing:

```
apiImg=$(base64 "$1") #my script takes the image as argument
```

But this gives me curl errors (too many arguments)

What am I supposed to do here ? I'm totally lost as how to send this base64 data to the server...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: are you using curl in this way? Can you paste you php code please?

Comment: The php code is on the image host side, it accepts the POST request I posted up there, but the image has to be an URL or an image base64 encoded

Comment: from where are you sending this data to the image host? And how are  u sending this data? with php or javascript?

Comment: I'm sending it from another server shell with bash

Comment: so is your question about bash?

Comment: Yes, about curl to be exact.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem might have to do with the -w flag of base64.
By default base64 inserts a newline every 76 chars.

Which results in output like this:

```
$ base64 ipsum.txt
TG9yZW0gaXBzdW0gZG9sb3Igc2l0IGFtZXQsIG1lbCBob21lcm8gcHJvbXB0YSBpZCwgdGUgaW1w
ZXJkaWV0IHByb2Rlc3NldCBjb25zZXRldHVyIHZpbSwgZXhlcmNpIHViaXF1ZSBhc3N1ZXZlcml0
IGV0IHZpeC4gQXQgZXVtIHZlcm8gdmlkZXJlciBzY3JpcHRvcmVtLiBBdXRlbSBjb25jZXB0YW0g
ZWFtIG5lLiBTZWQgYXQgc2VudGVudGlhZSBkaXNwdXRhbmRvLCB2aXggdXQgdmVsaXQgbW92ZXQu
IFVzdSBlc3NlIHRvdGEgdGUsIG5lYyBudW1xdWFtIHRpbmNpZHVudCB1dCwgYW5pbWFsIG1lbmFu
ZHJpIGV4cGV0ZW5kYSBhZCB1c3UuIEV1IHF1b3QgZXJhdCBwb3JybyBzZWQsIG5vIGVzdCBhcGVp
cmlhbiBjb25jbHVkYXR1cnF1ZS4=
```

Try adding -w 0, which just gives you the base64 in one long line.

```
$ base64 -w0 ipsum.txt
TG9yZW0gaXBzdW0gZG9sb3Igc2l0IGFtZXQsIG1lbCBob21lcm8gcHJvbXB0YSBpZCwgdGUgaW1wZXJkaWV0IHByb2Rlc3NldCBjb25zZXRldHVyIHZpbSwgZXhlcmNpIHViaXF1ZSBhc3N1ZXZlcml0IGV0IHZpeC4gQXQgZXVtIHZlcm8gdmlkZXJlciBzY3JpcHRvcmVtLiBBdXRlbSBjb25jZXB0YW0gZWFtIG5lLiBTZWQgYXQgc2VudGVudGlhZSBkaXNwdXRhbmRvLCB2aXggdXQgdmVsaXQgbW92ZXQuIFVzdSBlc3NlIHRvdGEgdGUsIG5lYyBudW1xdWFtIHRpbmNpZHVudCB1dCwgYW5pbWFsIG1lbmFuZHJpIGV4cGV0ZW5kYSBhZCB1c3UuIEV1IHF1b3QgZXJhdCBwb3JybyBzZWQsIG5vIGVzdCBhcGVpcmlhbiBjb25jbHVkYXR1cnF1ZS4=
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I tried that too before, and it gives the exact same error: /usr/bin/curl: Liste d'arguments trop longue (list of arguments too long)

Answer (score 0):

You should quote your url properly. & when not quoted places a command on the background:

```
curl -X POST "http://example.com/api?upload=${apiImg}&key=${apiKey}&format=xml"
```